# Why is the AUC of sine x from 0 to pi =2? I can calculate it using integration BUT it does not match intuitively expect looking at the unit circle

Tags: calculus

Area of a sine function:
I think I was able to add my diagrams

I have intuitive problems with this issue (area of sine function):
[image: Fig 1] showing area of circle

[image]

1. From a visual perspective using the unit circle:
   The area of a circle = πr^2.
   Then, in the case of the unit circle, the area would be π1^2=π=3.1416
   Thus, the area of half of the unit circle would be ½ π=1.571

As an object at location (1,0) on the unit circle sweeps across to (-1,0), it has swept from 0 to π (a circumference of π).
So, the area of y=sin⁡x from 0 to π should be 1.571. But it isn’t, it is 2

I have superimposed a 1 x 1 grid over the unit circle. To the eye, it appears to me that the area of half a circle is less than 2...and estimated to be 1.5, which I close to my calculated 1.57

But when I examine the area under the curve for the sine function from 0 to pi:

I can see just by rough estimation that the AUC is approximately 2

I cannot, no matter how hard I have tried, reconcile these two different ways of looking at the matter.

Comment: Why would $\int_0^\pi \sin(x)\,dx$ have anything in particular to do with the area of a semicircle?

Comment: What do AUC and BUT stand for?

Comment: @bof I would imagine that AUC is meant to mean *area under curve*, whereas BUT is just the word "but" synonymous to "however" written in all capital letters.  As to the question at hand, the matter of calculating the area of the semicircle versus calculating the area under the curve of $\sin(x)$ are two different problems.  On the one hand, if you were to try to add several small pieces together, for the semicircle case the pieces you are adding would be triangles (*or angular segments of the circle*) while in the other case you are adding rectangles.

Comment: The one case, you would have $\int\limits_0^\pi\int\limits_0^1 1\cdot r~dr~d\theta$ which is as you say $\frac{1}{2}\pi\approx 1.571$ (*note the use of $\approx$ not the use of* $=$).  In the other case you get $\int\limits_0^\pi \sin(x)~dx$ which is as you should know equal to $2$.

Answer (score 2):

The point $(x,y)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ moves along the circle, and as $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$, $x$ goes from $1$ to $-1$.  If you want $x$ to increase from $-1$ to $1$, then you need $\theta$ decreasing from $\pi$ to $0$.  So the area of the semi-circle that you describe is
$$
\frac \pi 2 = \int_{x=-1}^{x=1} (\text{height of the curve above the $x$-axis})\cdot dx = \int_{x=-1}^{x=1} \sin\theta\,dx.
$$
Note that
$$
\frac\pi2 = \int_{x=-1}^{x=1} \sin\theta\,dx \ne\int_0^\pi \sin\theta\,d\theta.
$$
I.e. $\underbrace{\sin\theta\,dx}$ is **different** from $\underbrace{\sin\theta\,d\theta}$. One of them has $dx$ where the other has $d\theta$.

Since $x=\cos\theta$, we have $\underbrace{dx=-\sin\theta\,d\theta}$, and that's not the same as $d\theta$.  In fact
$$
\int_{x=-1}^{x=1} \sin\theta\,dx = \int_{\theta=\pi}^{\theta=0} \sin\theta \Big({-\sin\theta\,d\theta}\Big) = \int_0^\pi \sin^2\theta\,d\theta.
$$

Calculus instruction does not give sufficient attention to the meanings of things like $dx$ and $d\theta$: they are infinitely small increments of $x$ and $\theta$.  And $x$ and $\theta$ change at different rates.  Speaking of infinitely small increments is immensely useful as a heuristic, and that's why you see that done in physics and engineering courses, but it's not in accord with modern standards of logical rigor.  Logical rigor gets idolatrously worshipped. It should be used rather than worshipped.

The integral $\displaystyle\int_0^\pi \sin\theta\,d\theta = 2 \ne \frac \pi 2$ is the area under the graph of the sine function.  Look closely and carefully at what that graph looks like and what the various measurements are.